# Find the when the maximum happens of this function.

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image: problem]
Myself and some coworkers have attempted to differentiate the function, solve for the min.

We have gotten that a maximum happens at x=ln(b/a)/(b-a), but the online platform is saying it’s wrong and there needs to be c’s involved??

Can someone attempt and explain why I’m wrong/ online platform is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by c'a? Also can you show what solution the online platform produced?

Comment: @PatrickJankowski my bad that was a typo, I meant c’s. The online platform did not give an answer, it simply said” your answer is incorrect, your answer must contain the constants a, b and c”.

Comment: No worries, yeah I also got the same answer as you @user338365

Answer (score 1):

The constant in front is irrelevant so let's differentiate $(e^{-at}-e^{-bt})'=-ae^{-at}+be^{-bt}=0 \to e^{-bt+at}=\frac{a}{b}$ or $t(a-b)=\ln a - \ln b$, $t=\frac{\ln a - \ln b}{a-b}$. Your answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  The $c$ scales the overall concentration, but does not affect the *time* at which a maximum occurs.  You can think of $c$ as merely setting the *units* you measure the concentration in.

Comment: Yeah I also graphed it with Desmos so I could see the answer graphically. To my surprise, the constant C had no change on the maximum. I’m still irked as to why it wouldn’t take our answer.